# how to access two adjoining elems in a seq while iterating through it

Tags: clojure

I have a seq `(2 3 1 4)`.

I want to iterate through it, and whereever the next element is smaller then the prev element replace both the elems another seq. '(- 4 1).

So  f('(2 3 1 4)) => (2 (- 3 1) 4). How do I write it?

Basically -

1) I want to access two adjoining elements in a seq at the same time.
2) Edit and return a new seq at that point.
3) Continue processing the new returned seq.

What is the mechanism to achieve the above 3 generically. (map, reduce both give me access to only one elem at a time.)

Comment: According to your description, shouldn't `f('(2 3 1 4)) => (2 3 (- 4 1))` evaluate to `('(- 3 2) '(- 4 1))`. Is this the desired output? Or would it be this:`('(- 3 2) 1 '(- 4 1))` ?

Comment: sorry for the wrong wording and ex. I have done the edits. Its where the next el is smaller than the prev. Have also changed the ex to reflect it.

Comment: That still seems odd to do in a generic way. In your example, the pairs are `([2 3] [3 1] [1 4])` and according to your requested output, on the first pair you want to keep the `2`, but on the last pair you want to keep the `4` which indicates a special case in the algorithm: namely that if we're on the last pair, we want to keep the second element if it's not smaller than the first. Is this correct?

Comment: Please check my answer, I added an UPDATE at the end. Is that what you're looking for?

Comment: The issue is that the next pair to check depends on whether the previous pair was replaced, so the pairs are not `([2 3] [3 1] [1 4])` but rather `([2 3] [3 1] [4])`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This isn't really an issue of pairwise consumption because how you partition your sequence depends on what you do with the current pair. Notice that sometimes you consume *one* item from the sequence (`2 3`), but sometimes you consume *two* items (`3 1`).

Because of this, you can't use any of the usual methods of creating a sliding window in clojure (`(partition 2 1 coll)`, `(map fn coll (rest coll))`, etc). You need to use something that is explicitly recursive.

Your algorithm should be this:

1. if empty seq emit nil
2. if only one item emit item
3. if two items, test for size:

   1. if first > second, replace both with `(- first second)`; recurse with remaining items
   2. otherwise, emit first; recurse with second and remaining items.

Here is a lazy implementation of this algorithm. You can also do this with `recur` and an accumulator--it won't be lazy but it will still work.

```
(defn combine-if-gt-next
  [[f s & r]]
  (cond
   (nil? f) nil
   (nil? s) (cons f nil)
   (> f s)  (cons (list '- f s) (lazy-seq (combine-if-gt-next r)))
   true (cons f (lazy-seq (combine-if-gt-next (cons s r))))))
```

Examples:

```
(combine-if-gt-next '(2 3 1 4)) ; your example
;; (2 (- 3 1) 4)
(combine-if-gt-next [])
;; nil
(combine-if-gt-next [1 2 3])
;; (1 2 3)
(combine-if-gt-next [2 3 4 1])
;; (2 3 (- 4 1))
(combine-if-gt-next [2 3 4 1 4])
;; (2 3 (- 4 1) 4)
(combine-if-gt-next [2 1 4 1 4 5 1])
;; ((- 2 1) (- 4 1) 4 (- 5 1))
(combine-if-gt-next [5 4 3 2 1])
;; ((- 5 4) (- 3 2) 1)
```

Comment: Francis thanks for the answer and the explanation on how to generally create the sliding window. I was getting tripped on how to access the f and s elements during recursion. The destructuring does that in a clever manner. Thanks!

Comment: Without destructuring you can accomplish the same with `first`, `second`, and `nnext` (note two "n"s). E.g., `(fn combine-if-gt-next [seq-arg] (let [f (first seq-arg) s (second seq-arg) r (nnext seq-arg)] FUNC-BODY))`.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure I understood your problem fully but I'll take a stab at it.

First we declare a var to hold your seq:

```
(def myseq '(2 3 1 4))
```

Then, we can zip the same sequence together, but at different starting points. 
That way we easily gain access to the previous element. This would return a seq of seqs, which is why we use `mapcat` to concatenate the results in the one list:

```
(mapcat
 (fn [prev curr]
   (if (< prev curr)
     [`(~'- ~curr ~prev)]
     [curr]))
 myseq (drop 1 myseq))

;; evaluates to((- 3 2) 1 (- 4 1))
```

Or if you're after my second proposed output:

```
(mapcat
 (fn [prev curr]
   (if (< prev curr)
     [`(~'- ~curr ~prev)]
     []))
 myseq (drop 1 myseq))

;; evaluates to ((- 3 2) (- 4 1))
```

Hope this helps.

**UPDATE**:

Ok, this gives you the output you want:

```
(mapcat
 (fn [prev curr idx]
   (cond
    (< curr prev) [`(~'- ~prev ~curr)]
    (= (+ idx 2) (count myseq)) [curr]
    :else [prev]))
 myseq (drop 1 myseq) (range (count myseq)))

;; evaluates to (2 (- 3 1) 4)
```

Hope this is what you're after.

Comment: +1 for the answer. Yours is a very clever answer, and thanks for it. I used the one from Francis as it was near what I already had.

Comment: also +1 for all your comments as I really liked ur ans. Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

[partition](http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_core/clojure.core/partition) and partition-all let you convert a sequence into batches of elements, using `(partition 2 1 data)` lets you iterate over a sliding window of pairs.

```
(def data '(2 3 1 4))

(loop [res [] pairs (partition-all 2 1 data)]
 (if-let [[l r] (first pairs)]
     (if (and r (< r l))
         (recur (conj res ['- l r]) (drop 2 pairs))
         (recur (conj res l) (rest pairs)))
     res))

;; returns [2 [- 3 1] 4]
```

Answer (score 1):

Does this solve what you need:

```
(defn my-fun [[f s & r]]
  (let [[flip next] (cond (and (nil? f) (nil? s)) ['() r]
                          (nil? f) [(list s) r]
                          (nil? s) [(list f) r]
                          (< s f) [(list (list (- f) s)) r]
                          :else [(list f) (cons s r)])]
    (if (nil? r)
      (concat flip next)
      (concat flip (my-fun next)))))


(my-fun '(2 3 1 4)) 
=> (2 (-3 1) 4)
(my-fun '(6 3 5 4))
=> ((-6 3) (-5 4))
```